# Android Vision: Detector dependencies are not yet available - ocr

Tags: android, google-play-services, ocr

I'm trying to create a simple App to detect a text using mobile camera, and I found [This](https://github.com/eddydn/AndroidCameraRecognitionText) tutorial. But it doesn't work with me... The error is

> **Detector dependencies are not yet available**

**Java:**

```
 TextRecognizer textRecognizer = new TextRecognizer.Builder(getApplicationContext()).build();

    if (!textRecognizer.isOperational()) {
        Toast.makeText(this,"Detector Dependies not available yet", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}
```

**Manifest:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<application> <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.vision.DEPENDENCIES"
        android:value="ocr"/> </application>
```

**Gradle:**

```
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:9.8.0'
```

I searched a lot and tried the below and unfortunately still not working...

- Updated Google Play Services.
- Cleared Google Play Services Cache.
- Free more than 10% of device memory.
- compiled the latest *com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision* Library.
- Rebooted device several times.